# avoid using multiple split method

Tags: java

I have a string like this.

```
   //Locaton;RowIndex;maxRows=New York, NY_10007;1;4
```

From this i need to get the contry name New York only.
   How it can possible in a single step code.

i used..

```
   String str = "Locaton;RowIndex;maxRows=New York, NY_10007;1;4 ";
   str = str.split("=")[1];
   str = str.split(",")[0]
```

the above code contails lots of splits.How can i avoid thiis.
   i want to get the contry name only using single code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this regular expression `"=(.*?),"` like this:

```
   String str = "Locaton;RowIndex;maxRows=New York, NY_10007;1;4 ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=(.*?),");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
   New York
```

> Using `matcher.group(1)` means capturing groups make it easy to extract part of the regex match,parentheses also create a numbered capturing group. 
>   It stores the part of the string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the parentheses.

```
 Match "Locaton;RowIndex;maxRows=New York, NY_10007;1;4 "
 Group 1: "New York"
```

Comment: Could you explain to a non regex expert like me why we need the "?" within the capture group?

Answer (score 1):

**Use capture groups with regex** which perfect capturing the specific data from string.

```
  String str = "Locaton;RowIndex;maxRows=New York, NY_10007;1;4 ";
   String pattern = "(.*?=)(.*?)(,.*)";
   Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

   Matcher m = r.matcher(str);

   if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Group 1: " + m.group(1));
       System.out.println("Group 2: " + m.group(2));
       System.out.println("Group 3: " + m.group(3));
   }
```

Here is the output

```
Group 1: Locaton;RowIndex;maxRows=
Group 2: New York
Group 3: , NY_10007;1;4
```